# Rails assets: Using a js/cofee variable for specifying name of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm still a little confused about the rails assets pipeline.

I have an array with a bunch of strings and each string has an image associated with it. I want the src of the image to equal the string + '.png'.

Here's some code that I tried to write (which doesn't work). I understand that the reason this doesn't work is because the ruby code is executed when compilation happens, but I'm not sure how else to do it. Thanks for your help!

`for flavor in flavors
    curFlavorImage = document.createElement('img')
    $(curFlavorImage).attr('src', "<%= asset_path('" + flavor['flavor'] + '.png' + "') %>")`

Comment: As @Baldrick says... You should learn to distinguish server side and client side. Server produces code, client can't work on. Client must send request to server to get response. Javascript can neither change nor build on ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flavor` is a javascript variable, it can't be used by the ruby/erb code.

If you have a fixed number of images, I would do like this:

```
var flavor_images = [];
flavor_images['flavor1'] = '<%= asset_path("flavor1.png") %>';
flavor_images['flavor2'] = '<%= asset_path("flavor2.png") %>';
// ...
for flavor in flavors 
   curFlavorImage = document.createElement('img') 
   $(curFlavorImage).attr('src', flavor_images[flavor['flavor']]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes complete sense